# Webpack 2 production build for Angular uses AOT internally or Do we need to do anything?

Tags: angular, webpack, aot

I am using webpack2 and angular. Production build generated using webpack configuration generates app.js(size above 2mb) and vendor.js(around 1.1mb) files which seems huge to me.

How to reduce these file sizes? Does webpack use AOT internally when we do a production build?

Comment: No. Using webpack2.0 with production enabled config which contains uglify plugin.

Comment: Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to decrease production build size/speed up your application. My recommendation list is:

1. Use AOT
2. Use Optimizing plugins, like `UglifyJS` & `OptimizeJS`
3. Lazy load your modules (this will not decrease final build size, but will decrease customer bandwith
4. Go on with Progressive Web Apps

You can check all of them in my angular-starter repo. Which can be found here:

https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa

https://www.angular-universal-pwa.maciejtreder.com